# Gulp-sass error with notify

Tags: sass, notify, gulp

I wondered if there is a way to have notify display a message on gulp-sass error. preferably the actual message that is displayed in the console.

my gulp task looks like this:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/scss/style.scss')
    .pipe(sass({ style: 'compressed', errLogToConsole: true }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(''))
    .pipe(livereload(server))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }));
});
```

I'd like to pipe the notify to some kind of error callback.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After struggling with this myself I found that this worked:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/scss/style.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
        style: 'compressed',
        errLogToConsole: false,
        onError: function(err) {
            return notify().write(err);
        }
    }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(''))
    .pipe(livereload(server))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }));
});
```

You need to catch the error using the `onError` option that gulp-sass provides.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Worth adding: `.pipe(sass(...).on('error', function() {...})` is not equivalent. It will catch the error but Sass won't run after the first error.

Comment: Great point, that was what I initially tried but forgot to mention that here.

Comment: I think you can use `{ onError: notify.onError('<%= error.message %>') }` and have sass continue to run after the first error.

Comment: For further reading see the [gulp-sass docs here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass)

Comment: I don't see anything about an `onError` handler in `gulp-sass` docs or `node-sass` docs. Where is this coming from?

Comment: @JakeWilson I think their API must have changed, this whole thread is out of date.

Answer (score 12):

I'm a little late to the party here but the issue I was having was that the sass would stop compiling if there was an error in the code and I would have to restart gulp. Here is what I ended up doing:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('assets/scss/style.scss')
        .pipe(sass({ errLogToConsole: false, }))
        .on('error', function(err) {
            notify().write(err);
            this.emit('end');
        })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))
        .pipe(notify({ message: 'SCSS Compiled' }));
});
```

In my case I had to add `this.emit('end');`

Comment: This solution worked for me with gulp-sass 2.0.4, when the accepted answer didn't worked with the latest version.

Comment: ...as for the stopping, you can use `.pipe(plumber())` from `gulp-plumber'right after `gulp.src()`.[What I am struggling with, is that I only see the first error, and only if that file just changed...]

Answer (score 4):

With gulp-sass v2.0.4, this works:

```
.pipe(sass())
.on('error', notify.onError(function (error) {
   return 'An error occurred while compiling sass.\nLook in the console for details.\n' + error;
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is works too:

```
/* Compile sass, and output error to notif */
    .pipe(sass({}).on('error', function(err) {
        return notify().write(err);
    }))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we should also print in the console and this code works in the current version of gulp-sass(4.0.1)

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src('src/sass/style.scss')
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'}).on('error',function(err) {
            sass.logError;  //I think we should also print in the console
            return notify().write(err); //and the notification bar
        }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({browsers:autoprefixBrowsers}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
    .pipe(notify({message: 'sass compiled successfully'}));
});
```